# Alternative to getElementById - How to affect multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to highlight all the words in a paragraph and keep them red when clicked. Now I got it worked for one word but the others won't follow.
https://jsfiddle.net/q1z7Lnv0/

```
<p><span id="word" class="notclicked">test</span> <span id="word" class="notclicked">test</span></p>
```

Javascript :

```
    var word = document.getElementById("word");
    word.onclick = function() {
      if(word.className == "clicked"){
            word.className = 'notclicked';
        }
      if(word.className == "onmouse"){
            word.className = 'clicked';
        }
    }
    word.onmouseover = function onMouse(){
        if(word.className != "clicked"){
        word.className = 'onmouse';
      }
    }
    word.onmouseout = function onMouse(){
        if(word.className != "clicked"){
        word.className = 'notclicked';
      }
    }
```

I know the problem is that there can only be one id with the same name. But I don't know what other alternative I could use.

Please help!

Comment: onclick you need to set red to whole word inside the p  tag so use class name instead of id

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('word');
```

And in your html:

```
<span class='word'>text</span>
```

This way you'll get all the elements that have the class name "word" and you can bind the events to the class instead of the elements.

You'll have to modify your code to get the targeted word and only add and/or remove your click classes from that one word instead of all the words with the class 'word'

for example:

```
word.onclick = function(e) {
    if(e.target.className == "clicked"){
            e.target.className = 'notclicked';
    }if(e.target.className == "onmouse"){
        e.target.className = 'clicked';
    }
}
```

I am not 100% certain that you can modify the classname of the target using the Event interface, so take this example as pseudo-code rather than copy-paste able code.

In case you are not familiar with the "e" I put as a parameter in your function, it is the Event interface for all javascript events. It always gets passed on to the event function, and you can use that to get all the necessary information about your event.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to do this. One approach could be to add a class instead of id to those elements you want to access. Then you can get them using `getElementsByClassName`.

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/q1z7Lnv0/1/

Answer (score -1):

you can use class in place of id as an alternative alias.